Issue with Login and Registration flow in Android App
I have implemented a login and registration within the app using Firebase Authentication in my Android app. The problem I'm facing is that after successfully entering my phone number and OTP in the LoginActivity, the app is redirecting to the MainActivity instead of the intended RegisterActivity.
I have already created a test phone number and OTP in the Firebase Authentication section. Despite providing correct login credentials, the registration process is not initiating.
I have attached the LoginActivity code for your reference:
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityLoginBinding

    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    private var verificationId: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.sendOtp.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.userNumber.text!!.isEmpty()) {
                binding.userNumber.error = "Please enter your number"

            } else {
                sendOtp(binding.userNumber.text.toString())
            }
        }
        binding.verifyOtp.setOnClickListener {
            if (binding.userOtp.text!!.isEmpty()) {
                binding.userOtp.error = "Please enter your OTP"

            } else {
                verifyOtp(binding.userOtp.text.toString())
            }

        }
    }

    private fun verifyOtp(otp: String) {
        val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId!!, otp)
        signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
    }

    private fun sendOtp(number: String) {
        val callbacks = object : PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

            override fun onVerificationCompleted(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
            }

            override fun onVerificationFailed(e: FirebaseException) {
            }

            override fun onCodeSent(
                verificationId: String,
                token: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken,
            ) {
                this@LoginActivity.verificationId = verificationId

                binding.numberLayout.visibility = GONE
                binding.otpLayout.visibility = VISIBLE

            }
        }
        val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber("+49$number")
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(this)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .build()
        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)

    }


    private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                    finish()

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, task.exception!!.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

I verified that I have set up Firebase Authentication correctly. I created a test phone number and OTP in the Firebase Authentication console to simulate the login process. I made sure that the phone authentication method is enabled in the Firebase project settings.

Redirecting to the main activity seems to be exactly what your code does here: startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)). If you want to redirect somewhere else, you'll want to change that part of the code.
